# ZXing Xamarin Forms iOS white background (without Custom Renderer)

Tags: ios, xamarin, xamarin.forms, zxing

I have implemented the ZXing.Xamarin.Mobile.**Forms** QR scanner(Nuget package) with custom overlay.

In Android it is working nicely, but in iOS I'm getting no scanner and a white background.

The package is added to the iOS project as well.

Has anyone experienced this?

I know how to program it using Custom Renderers so I'm not interested in answers regarding this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Have you added the init() in your AppDelegate and MainActivity ?

From samples:

**Android:**

https://github.com/Redth/ZXing.Net.Mobile/blob/master/Samples/Forms/Droid/MainActivity.cs

**iOS:**

https://github.com/Redth/ZXing.Net.Mobile/blob/master/Samples/Forms/iOS/AppDelegate.cs

Comment: how about for windows phone? is it not needed?